# How to inject html to below Python script?

Tags: python

facing a following problem and not sure how to proceed. In the generate_msg function instead of the content as per below code snip I would like to pass an HTML code, so the email generated will be in html format. currently its being received by Outlook as plain text.

```
import json
import sys
import time
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

email_server = "smtp.email.com"
email_from = "noreply@example.com"


def generate_msg(alert):
    """
    Function that will provide the custom subject and body for the email.
    It takes as input a dictionary object generated from the json alert
    """
    description = alert['rule']['description']
    level = alert['rule']['level']
    agentname = alert['agent']['name']
    t = time.strptime(alert['timestamp'].split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    timestamp = time.strftime('%c',t)

    subject = 'Wazuh Alert: {0}, {1}'.format(description, agentname)

    message = """
    This is an automatic message from your Wazuh Instance.
    
    On {a} an event from agent "{b}" triggered the rule "{c}" of level {d}.
    The full contents of the alert are:
    {e}
    """.format(a=timestamp,b=agentname,c=description,d=level,e=json.dumps(alert,indent=4))

    return subject, message


# Additional global vars
debug_enabled = False
pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
json_alert = {}
now = time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")

# Set paths
log_file = '{0}/logs/integrations.log'.format(pwd)

def main(args):
    """
    Main function. This will call the functions to prepare the message and send the email 
    """
    debug("# Starting")

    # Read args
    alert_file_location = args[1]
    recipients = args[3]
 
    debug("# Webhook")
    debug(recipients)

    debug("# File location")
    debug(alert_file_location)

    # Load alert. Parse JSON object.
    with open(alert_file_location) as alert_file:
        json_alert = json.load(alert_file)
    debug("# Processing alert")
    debug(json_alert)

    debug("# Generating message")
    subject, msg = generate_msg(json_alert)
    debug(msg)

    debug("# Sending message")
    send_email(recipients, subject, msg)

def send_email(recipients,subject,body):
    """
    Function to send email using an unautheticated email server.
    """
    TO = recipients.split(',')
    em = EmailMessage()
    em.set_content(body)
    em['To'] = TO
    em['From'] = email_from 
    em['Subject'] = subject
    try:
        # SMTP_SSL Example
        mailserver = smtplib.SMTP(email_server, 25)
        mailserver.ehlo() # optional, called by login()
        mailserver.send_message(em)
        mailserver.close()
        debug('Successfully sent the mail to {}'.format(TO))
    except Exception as e:
        debug("Failed to send mail to {}".format(TO))
        debug("With error: {}".format(e))

def debug(msg):
    """
    Function to generate debug logs
    """
    if debug_enabled:
        msg = "{0}: {1}\n".format(now, msg)
        print(msg)
        f = open(log_file, "a")
        f.write(msg)
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Read arguments
        bad_arguments = False
        if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
            msg = '{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}'.format(
                now,
                sys.argv[1],
                sys.argv[2],
                sys.argv[3],
                sys.argv[4] if len(sys.argv) > 4 else '',
            )
            debug_enabled = (len(sys.argv) > 4 and sys.argv[4] == 'debug')
        else:
            msg = '{0} Wrong arguments'.format(now)
            bad_arguments = True

        # Logging the call
        f = open(log_file, 'a')
        f.write(msg + '\n')
        f.close()

        if bad_arguments:
            debug("# Exiting: Bad arguments.")
            sys.exit(1)

        # Main function
        main(sys.argv)

    except Exception as e:
        debug(str(e))
        raise
```

tried pasting

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #ffffff;
                text-align: Center;
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }
            p {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: Center;
                color: #2f2d2d;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ALERT</h1>  
    </body>
</html>
```

within """ but no joy, arrived as plain text.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) templating engine that can be used to fill html programatically using Python code.

Comment: does it work if you specify the content subtype: `em.set_content(body, subtype='html')`? There is a more comprehensive example of creating an HTML email in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

Comment: You can use Jinja template and it is much easier to render html with python variables

Comment: @Aaron this worked, thank you so much

Comment: @YuriR matszwecja thank you both for suggesting JinJa